# Avoiding deserialized class adding multiple items to lists in constructor

Tags: c#, json

I have a class like this:

```cs
public class MyClass
{
    public OtherClass Other { get; set; } = new OtherClass();
    public OtherClass Another { get; set; } = new OtherClass();
    
    public List<OtherClass> Others { get; set; } = new List<OtherClass>();

    public MyClass()
    {
        Others.Add(Other);
        Others.Add(Another);
    }
}
```

Basically, I have a bunch of properties of another class and I add them to the list so I can display them in the UI somewhere. I also iterate through this list in some places to work out, for examples, totals of some properties.

I've got some basic persistent storage of this class data by serializing it into a JSON file (Newtonsoft.Json).

What I've found is that when I de-serialize it from the JSON file, I'm ending up with duplicates in the `List<OtherClass>`. My assumption is that the class is being instantiated via `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` and then the constructor method is running, resulting in the same objects being added twice (this tracks with the order of the list in my JSON if I serialize it and look at file afterwards).

I could do something like this to avoid this problem:

```
public MyClass()
{
    if (!Others.Any(p => p.ID == Other.ID)
    {
        Others.Add(Other);
    }

    if (!Others.Any(p => p.ID == Another.ID)
    {
        Others.Add(Another);
    }
}
```

But this is quite a lot of extra code if I have many properties.

Is there a better way I can create my class so that it works when creating normally `MyClass newClass = new MyClass();` and also via JSON de-serialization.

Alternatively, is there a simpler way I can achieve my example solution?

Comment: The question is, why do you even need to have a public list with getters and setters? You can return the list only when needed building it on the spot.  No way to add other classes then

Comment: You can attach the `[JsonIgnore]` attribute over `Others` property. So that during deserialization and serialization the property is not included.

Comment: @Steve Two reasons: I bind it to a drop down list in the UI which allows users to change various properties of the class (e.g. `OtherClass.UserProvidedValue`), I additionally have a few routines which run loop the list and total various properties of the objects in the list (e.g. `TotalUserProvidedValues`).

Comment: @user1672994 That's good to know, although doesn't help in this case because I do want to serialize the `Others` properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several options here. Perhaps none of them is ideal.

1. Initialize the `Others` list outside of the default constructor:

```
public MyClass() { }

public void Initialize()
{
    Others.Add(Other);
    Others.Add(Another);
}
```

2. Modify the constuctor:

```
public MyClass(bool initialize = false) 
{
    if (initialize)
    {
        Others.Add(Other);
        Others.Add(Another);
    }
}
```

3. You could create multiple constructors and specify one using the [ConstructorHandling setting](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeConstructorHandling.htm) or the [JsonConstructor Attribute](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonConstructorAttribute.htm).
4. Use a mapping library such as automapper to map from `MyClass` to another class before serialization, deserialize to that class and map back to `MyClass`. Your mapping configuration could contain logic for excluding members from the list.
5. Serialize a copy that has those properties excluded from the list. They will get added back in during deserialization:

```
public class MyClass
    {
        public OtherClass Other { get; set; } = new OtherClass();
        public OtherClass Another { get; set; } = new OtherClass();
        public List<OtherClass> Others { get; set; } = new List<OtherClass>();

        public MyClass()
        {
            Others.Add(Other);
            Others.Add(Another);
        }

        public MyClass CreateCopyForSerizlization()
        {
            return new MyClass()
            {
                Other = this.Other,
                Another = this.Another,
                Others = this.Others.Except(new List<OtherClass>() { Other, Another }).ToList()
            };
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think your second suggestion is probably the simplest, but I'll have a play with the other suggestions too. I think really I need to evaluate the design of my appliction more broadly...